# How can I stop Safari from always asking permission to open Zoom?

Tags: safari, zoom.app

[image: Safari prompting for permission to open Zoom]

I want to immediately open Zoom links without the annoying question EVERY SINGLE TIME.  How can I just open Zoom and get on with my meetings?

A similar question is posted on the Apple forums but no one has a good answer: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253451980

Comment: The short answer is that there are no solutions, only workarounds to avoid getting to the point where the prompt occurs

Comment: If SE sites had a decent search for the list of "Similar Questions", there would not be so many duplicates.

Comment: Also, the text of the other question specifically EXCLUDES browsers, therefore I'm not sure how ANYONE could possibly have seen that and thought it might have the answer.  Safari is a browser, how is a question about Safari "the same question" as a question about non-browser apps????

Comment: If you read the question, they mean zoom to be the non-browser app, not Safari

Comment: @Ezekiel my previous comments were just comments on the closing, not directed specifically at you, by the way.  But with regard to the other question, you might be right, but then in that case their wording of the question is extremely poor and misleading.  They effectively mention Zoom twice but not the other app, and the other app is actually the app that opens the link.  The zoom link triggers Zoom, but is never "IN" Zoom, so everything about their wording is non-sensical (if they meant it in the way you describe)

Comment: Gotcha no worries